# install binary gems with bundler

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, arm, bundler

A project that use bundle requires many gems that are compiled on install time. My problem is that I cannot compile on the device ( long story short: I'm on android ). So I cross compiled those native gems, installed them manually ( `gem install test-1.0-arm-linux.gem` ) and everything goes fine.

Now I have 2 ways to achieve this without manual install:

1. extract cross compiled gems into `vendor/cache`
2. use a private gem server

The first solution works fine, but I have to download a big tarball each time that I have to fix some bug on a gem. I will prefer the second solution, but that seems to not work.

I had setup geminabox on my localhost and pushed my cross compiled gems over it. Added it's url to the sources ( `gem sources -a http://localhost:9292/` ) but bundler will prefer downloading and compile gems from *rubygems.org*.

How can I force it downloading cross compiled gems?

According the PLATFORMS section of the [Gemfile manual](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html) `arm-linux` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found.
The [SOURCE PRIORITY section of the Gemfile manual](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-PRIORITY) specify that sources in Gemfile will be used in the reverse order that they appear, so I just added my private server in the Gemfile after *rubygems.org* and everything goes fine. I also removed my source from gems with:

```
gem sources -r 'http://localhost:9292/
```

I hope that this helps someone.
Regards